# How to run a function after returning a value in another function

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I want to run a function `validatefile()` after returning value from `checkFileType()`. Is there any way??

```
function checkFileType(obj)
{
    if (!( (/.jpg$/.test(obj.value))||(/.gif$/.test(obj.value))||(/.jpeg$/.test(obj.value)) ||(/.png$/.test(obj.value)) ||(/.mp4$/.test(obj.value)) ))
    {
       alert('Please Select Image/Vedio File. \n Supported File Formats are jpeg,gif,png,mp4.');
       obj.className = 'err';
       obj.value="";
       document.getElementById("adfileval").value=0;
       document.getElementById("prevdata").value=0;
       return false;
    }
    else
    { 
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you called `checkFileType` ?

Comment: You are missing piece of your code in your question

Comment: you can use callbacks.. or pormises

Comment: i called this during file upload onchange

Comment: Is this code supposed to be asynchronous?

Comment: When you call `checkFileType ` and get the response why not just call `validatefile` then? So in the calling code. No code is executed after a `return` statement, it simply returns or exits from the function. If you want to send a value out and continue executing the function you will need to use either promises or callbacks.

Comment: checkFileType() return a file path and i need that file path in another function

Comment: In your code `checkFileType()` returns `true` or `false` not a file path.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `checkFileType` from the `onChange` event, call a function that calls `checkFileType` and then calls `validateFile`.